# ASP IdentityUser ApplicationUser - How to register multiple times

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, identity, usermanager

I have a database setup with the AspNetUsers table, and I am using the default code provided in a .NET solution for registration, login, password reset and so on.

The database is to be run across multiple websites, so I need to account for the possibility that one user with a given email address may sign up to two of our sites. I have this code to create a new user, after validation and other setup:-

```
var applicationUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = user.Email, Email = user.Email, RevolveID = revolveID, CandidateID = candidate.CandidateID };
var registrationResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(applicationUser, user.Password);
```

I test registrationResult for the Success status, but on debugging this fails, because my email is already taken. I need this to be able to deal with me signing up multiple times. I've seen there is an IsEnabled column, but this may not help across sites because two accounts on different sites may both be enabled at the same time?

What is the best way round this? Is it best to manually create a user in this table? I've added a SiteID column to the AspNetUsers table as a mark to distinguish between sites, but I have no access to alter the ApplicationUser functionality to make it account for this.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Thanks!
Mike.

Comment: Creating a duplicate user from anywhere, should fail. This is expected behaviour. You should look for SSO, refer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic

Answer (score 0):

A little late. If the issue is a duplicate email address (not a duplicate username), this piece of code in my custom UserManager fixed it:

```
manager.UserValidator = New UserValidator(Of ApplicationUser, Integer)(manager) With {
          .AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = False,
          .RequireUniqueEmail = False
        }
```

The essential piece of course is setting RequireUniqueEmail to false.

Sorry, VB, not my choice!